# Is writing to file considered dangerous in PHP?

Tags: php, web-services

Say I have this PHP file:

```
<?php
$file = 'prism.csv';
// Open the file to get existing content
$current = file_get_contents($file);
// Append a new person to the file
$current .= $_POST['user'];
$current .= ";";
$current .= $_POST['score0'];
$current .= ";";
$current .= $_POST['score1'];
$current .= ";";
$current .= $_POST['score2'];
$current .= ";";
$current .= $_POST['score3'];
$current .= "\n";
// Write the contents back to the file
file_put_contents($file, $current);
?>
```

Is writing to a file like this dangerous and how can it be exploited in a case of a attack? My friend says it is but he can't give me a example. How can I secure this file?

Comment: As a rule of thumb you *never* want to have any file under the docroot able to be written to by the web server; a flaw in your application could mean anyone could rewrite that file to anything (theoretically) and then just execute it by opening it in their browser.

Comment: Not dangerous, but you're creating a csv wrong, it would be trivial to break it so it cant be parsed out.

Comment: As an aside, you might want to look at [fgetcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) and [fputcsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) since you seem to be working with CSV data.

Comment: Assuming that this file is not located under the web server's document root, the exploitability of this particular case would depend mostly on how the CSV file is being used after it's written.

Comment: @AlexHowansky - looks like the receiving file *is* under the docroot otherwise you couldn't `POST` to it - and `prism.csv` is in the same dir.

Comment: @CD001 I mean the CSV file itself, not the PHP file that creates it. (Not sure if the hardcoded filename here has been stripped of full path for brevity.)

Comment: @AlexHowansky - yeah, sorry, I just clarified my comment; `prism.csv` is in the same dir.

Comment: You don't need the `file_get_contents` use `FILE_APPEND`. You also don't need one variable per line, you can do multiple concatenations on a line.

Comment: Not dangerous? @LawrenceCherone he pushes in untrusted user data without escaping .. This could be dangerous if this CSV is included into PHP again attacks like Cross site scripting or SQL injections could be possible then.

Comment: The file is to be used by admins to check user progress.(Online system for school / collage)

Comment: Called by $.post("prism.php", { user: $("#user").val(), score0: A, score1: B, score2: C, score3: D }, function (data) { /*alert(data);*/ });

Comment: Thanks for your feedback

Comment: @RaymondNijland You think the OP is using a database? Your reaching.. Anyways adding SQL queries to it wont magically make it an SQL injection would it?.. Your presuming the OP is not using prepared queries and an attacker knows which parameters to inject into.... If anything it would break it for parsing out later, then the danger is non-existent lol An adding PHP code to a csv doesn't magically get parsed when it's accessed.. I dont see any output how could a XSS happen?

Comment: Your presuming "Not dangerous" is even more dangerours @LawrenceCherone  "I dont see any output how could a XSS happen? " CSV contains html or script tags and PHP echos these CSV fields direclty into html generated webpage..

Comment: I don't see the storing of this as dangerous. The usage of it is a different question though. XSS and/or SQL injections could be present.

Comment: @RaymondNijland csv files have a mime type `text/csv` or `text/plain`, servers dont output as `text/html` so html wont be parsed, and unless you setup the server to run csv files through php, the php is not parsed.. Your essentially saying if you enter php or an sql statement in a `.log` or text file its going to be parsed which is wrong.. dont call me out before checking your facts..

Comment: "csv files have a mime type text/csv or text/plain, servers dont output as text/html so html wont be parsed" read ? @LawrenceCherone "CSV contains html or script tags and PHP echos these CSV fields direclty into html generated webpage" chris85 also supports this it's all about the usage of the csv file..

Comment: Show me an example of a .csv file execting html or javascript with a mime type `text/csv` or php executed from a csv value and ill eat my words..

Comment: "Show me an example of a .csv file execting html or javascript with a mime type text/csv or php executed from a csv value and ill eat my words" -> simple php cvs parsing and directly echo the untrusted fields from the cvs into a webpage is more than enough to get a cross site scripting going.

Comment: Your presuming that htmlentities is not used, dont forget.. the OP could be using eval on each of the values as well.  ;p